# Why gadgets are avoided in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, desktop-gadget

In Windows 7, there were gadgets like clock, calender, weather etc. But in Windows 8, no gadgets are there.

Why Microsoft avoided gadgets in Windows 8 ?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/gadgets

Comment: Because it was discoverd that gadgets were a security risk. Because only a small minority even used them they were simply removed from Windows 8.

Comment: See Frank Thomas's reply to LPChip's answer for your reason. However, I suggest you look into Rainmeter to achieve a similar style that Windows's gadgets gave you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Micrsoft stopped supporting gadgets all together. Not just in windows 8, but in 7 as well. There used to be a library available where you could download gadgets for windows 7, but Microsoft stopped with this a year ago. In Windows 8, you have Metro with tiles which is supposed to be the replacement for gadgets.

Comment: Note that the reason for this, is that they could not reconcile the gadget model with the admin-approval model used in UAC, which lead to gadgets being inherently over-privldged, allowing any exploit against vulnerabilities in the gadget itself to perform actions that would otherwise be impermissible. https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/2719662

Comment: Indeed, Frank's reply answers the question that was asked.